# Old hard disk does not load OS

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, hard-drive, upgrade, liveusb

I have this old computer but upgraded the motherboard and the processor just recently. Everything was already used except for the motherboard, processor and RAM. The rest, was already used, the hard drive already contains the previous windows XP OS.

So when I already tested my computer after building it, it ran quite well. I can visit the BIOS and all but I cannot boot to the previous OS.

The following are the options presented to me:

- Safe mode
- Safe mode with networking
- Safe mode with command prompt
- Last known good configuration
- Start windows normally

Neither of the above options boot to the OS. When I select any of those, it will just restart the option selection and just show that message again(without restarting the whole computer). Of course when I select the safe mode options, there are some codes and directories that will appear but will still repeat the options after showing some directories. When I select the start normally, it shows the windows logo and the loading bar but it does not load and just proceeds to the option selection again.

So what I did was to try to boot to my live ubuntu USB. So at startup, I do press DEL and it will bring me to the ASUS BIOS. In the boot menu section, there are 3 items, which is weird; i think it should only be 2.

The items are:

- My SATA Hard disk
- Generic USB...
- UEFI Generic USB

When I select the Generic USB to boot to my live ubuntu, it present the screen with the circle-and-man-below-logo then I need to press any key and I did. It shows the language select options then the main screen where I get to choose to use live, install or etc.

I selected the live option then it just turns to black after that. And in fact any option leads to that.

---

Now, selecting the UEFI Generic USB in the BIOS boot menu will give me a  different list.

- Try ubuntu without installing
- Install Ubuntu
- OEM something
- some other option i forgot

I selected Try Ubuntu without installing which is pretty much the live ubuntu thing. After that, my monitor flashes different colors(pink, green, yellow, and many more) and continue to do that unless I restart my computer.

So what should I do? What are the reasons for this? How can I test if my new computer really can boot to an OS or is my hard drive broken?

By the way, I don't still know if the hard drive is corrupted or what. And I actually want to install a new operating system and remove the old win XP but I still tried to boot to the old win XP and also tried in a live USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About Windows XP, it will never boot, because all the hardware has been changed, and now windows has an incorrect drivers for all the hardware.

About Ubuntu, i don't know!
But, it looks like you have a hardware issue.

Comment: interesting, so what should I do for that to boot? how can I install appropriate drivers?

Comment: You can reinstall windows over the previous installation (repair), don't format.

Comment: can I directly install a windows 8 using a live usb? and would it replace the old win xp? And I also did not directly try because I still want to verify if my new computer can really work and boot to an OS. But for the case of ubuntu it did not.

Comment: Sure you can install win8 from usb, it will format the hard disk and have a fresh install without backing up your files.
Maybe Ubuntu could not recognize your hardware, that's why did not work, and maybe Windows 8 will recognize them and work, give it a try.

Comment: will try this, thanks for the help. will give u an accepted answer once it works.